# munkres analysis integration question

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $[0,1]^2 = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. Let $f: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting $f(x,y)=0$ if $y \neq x$, and $f(x,y) = 1$ if $y=x$. Show that $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: what kind of integral are you using?  With the Lebesgue integral, the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Given $ \varepsilon>  0 $ is $ k \in \ N $ such that $\varepsilon >1/k$ consider a 'homogeneous' partition of $ [0,1] \times [0,1] $, i.e., all sub- rectangles of partition has area $1/k^2$, we know that $ m_B =  0$ and $ m_B = 1$ if $B$ intection the line $ y = x $ is not empty set, so 
$ S (f, P)-s (f, P) = \sum_ {B \ in P} (m_B-m_B) vol (B) = \sum_ {B \mbox {such that intection the line $ y = x $ is not empty set}} = 1 / k <\varepsilon $ hence f is integrable .

Comment: Can you please write a bit more clearly? What do you mean $m_B = 0$ and $m_B$ if B intection...?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider the partition $P$ like the above picture.

$U(f, P) - L(f, P) = \frac{3 n - 2}{n^2}$.

$\frac{3 n - 2}{n^2} \to 0 (n \to \infty)$.

So, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$.

By Theorem 10.3 (p.86), $f$ is integrable over $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.